# repository not signed error with sourcelist

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I am getting this weird error when I'm trying to execute apt update on linux mint.
Any recommendations how i can fix this?

```
Reading package lists... Done
    E: The repository 'http://www.sourceslist.eu/repo/ubuntu lucid Release' is not signed.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is my sources.list

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 19.1 _Tessa_ - Release amd64 20181217]/ bionic contrib main non-free
deb http://www.sourceslist.eu/repo/ubuntu lucid main non-free
```

Comment: I do not think Ubuntu 10.04 repositories are going to be active at this point. Are you using Linux Mint or Ubuntu? Please edit your post with the contents of your sources.list and please clarify what your Operating system is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not using `Ubuntu` and so cannot test this, but reading the `man` pages for `apt-secure(8)` as suggested by the error message and going from there to `sources.list(5)`, it appears that if you are desperate to stay on `lucid` you need to edit your `sources.list` to allow insecure downgrade.

From the `man` pages the syntax is probably

```
deb [ allow-downgrade-to-insecure=yes ] http://www.sourceslist.eu/repo/ubuntu lucid main non-free
```

BEWARE: this downgrading is clearly stated as a potential security risk.

The better option would be to upgrade your release. Apparently this can be done without a reinstall, even from obsolete releases to current and this is detailed in the [Ubuntu Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)..... but back-up first if you do.

One other thing you could try **first** is changing your mirror to the one in in the upgrade instructions and see if that one is still signed, I would assume it should be. This is on the Ubuntu Community link above and is probably as below

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main non-free
```

though a quick browse on the repository ftp didn't reveal a `non-free` element.

This solution appears otherwise to have worked for [these good people](https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/07/31/apt-repository-for-old-ubuntu-releases/)